# biblatex: Defining finalnamedelim for different parts of a bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-mla

I am formatting a bibliography using `biblatex-mla`. MLA style (at least up to the version I am using, and still the current stable configuration of `biblatex-mla`) requires the string `, and` between the second-last and the last author of a work, but `biblatex-mla` omits the comma:

[image: Comma missing after Dudley, Donald R.]

Note the missing comma ahead of "and". Rather too general a solution is the following:

```
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space\bibstring{and}\space}
```

This adds the comma not just here, but also in the editor section of an entry like the following, where it should not be:

[image: An unwanted comma after Magennis]

How can I modify the delimiter for the initial author/editor section only, leaving the later here's-the-editor-of-this-multi-author-volume section intact?

I'm using biber as a backend.

Comment: Does the style even require the comma before an 'and' in a list with only two names? Note that I get a comma before the 'and' in the byeditor list if there are more than two names by default. So can you check that this is really what MLA wants?

Comment: @moewe That's what the examples in their _Handbook_ suggest. Only when the last name comes first, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to redefine `\revsdnamedelim` (not `\finalnamedelim`):

```
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{\addcomma}
```

Here's a MWE with the defaults of `mla-new` (8th edition):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dudley+webster:1965,
  author = {Dudley, Donald R. and Webster, Graham},
  title = {The Roman Conquest of Britain AD 43--57},
  location = {Chester Springs, PA},
  publisher = {Dufour},
  date = {1965}
}
@inbook{swan:2009,
  author = {Swan, Mary},
  title = {Identity and Ideology in {\AE}lfric's Prefaces},
  booktitle = {A Companion to {\AE}lfric},
  editor = {Magennis, Hugh and Swan, Mary},
  series = {Brill's Companions to the Christian Tradition},
  number = {18},
  location = {Leiden and Boston},
  publisher = {Brill},
  date = {2009},
  pages = {247-269}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{\addcomma}
\begin{document}
\autocite{dudley+webster:1965}
\autocite{swan:2009}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a very clever trick and it works in the MWE thanks to a combination of several factors: By default in `mla-new` (1) there will always be an Oxford comma before the 'and' in list of more than two names and (2) never in lists of two. (3) `mla-new` uses a particular name format, namely `family-given/given-family` where only the first name is reversed. (4) `\revsdnamedelim` is only printed in two-name lists if the first name is reversed. Not sure if all of this is in the spirit of the OP's question, but (+1) nonetheless.

Comment: @moewe, is this really a clever trick? My reading of the `biblatex` manual suggests that this is a feature and the right way to do this. The Oxford comma is controlled by `\finalandcomma`. SBL style also requires names in this format in the bibliography and no great modification of the standard styles are needed. the `family-given/given-family` name format comes straight out of the standard `biblatex` styles.

Comment: Well, I was not entirely sure what the OP wanted to see in the case of three names. There with your solution he would always get a comma before 'and'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a strange distinction that they make. But I don't decide. The problem with the "editor" stuff is that biblatex has a `\currentname` that is "editor" for an editor entry. Alas, this is used both for the "editor" and the "edited by" fields. Fortunately, the "edited by"is passed as the first optional parameter (format) to `\printnames`, but that isn't publicly available. So you must redefine `\printnames` to give you that information, and then use it in `\finalnamedelim`.

Here is some code. Hope this works in your situation.

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newprintnames}{oom}{%
  \def\currentformat{#1}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\originalprintnames[#1]{#3}}%
  {\originalprintnames[#1][#2]{#3}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{\let\originalprintnames\printnames\let\printnames\newprintnames}

\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\currentformat}{byeditor}}%
     {}% Nothing if "edited by"
     {\addcomma}% comma otherwise
     \space\bibstring{and}\space
}
```

Comment: No need to do this. `biblatex` has a lot of different types of delimiters which can all be separately defined to give the output you want, e.g., `\finalnamedelim`, `\finalandcomma`, `\multinamedelim`, and `revsdnamedelim`. See §3.10.1 of the `biblatex` manual.